# Ajax won't pass data to php file

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I am trying to pass canvas data to a .php file with Ajax (no jQuery) and POST.

Unfortunately, $_POST is NULL in my .php file..

JS

```
function takepicture()
{
  //...
  var canvasData = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");

  const req = new XMLHttpRequest();
  req.open('POST', '../controller/pictureController.php', true);

  req.onreadystatechange = function() {
      // XMLHttpRequest.DONE === 4
      if (this.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {
          if (this.status === 200) {
              console.log("Response: %s", this.responseText);
          } else {
              console.log("Response status : %d (%s)", this.status, this.statusText);
          }
      }
  };

  req.send(canvasData);
}
```

PHP

```
saveData($_POST['canvasData']);

function saveData($data)
{
    $input = $data;
    //...
    file_put_contents($output, file_get_contents($input));
}
```

The response is: `file_get_contents(): Filename cannot be empty` which is normal as `var_dump(canvasData)` is `NULL`.

When I console.log `canvasData` from the JS part the image string is present so I guess something is passed through `send(canvasData)` right?

How can I get the data in my php file?

Comment: Have you debugged the data before you send it to the server? What is the output of `console.log(canvasData)`?

Comment: @Jerodev Said it in my question :) `console.log(canvasData)` outputs the image data: `data:image/png...`

Comment: `req.send(canvasData);` where `canvasData` is the data... but you have NOT specified the querystring, ie: `req.send( 'canvasData='+canvasData )` so the POST var does not exist

Comment: @RamRaider Thanks a lot, I just discovered query strings thanks to you, unfortunately `var_dump($_POST['canvasData'])` is still `NULL` in my php file

Comment: As a pure test to see if the mechanism works simply send a static string as the payload and inspect the response. ie: `req.send( 'canvasData=geronimo' )`

Comment: `Response: NULL` again

Comment: your php script: does it echo anything?

Comment: No, just `var_dump($_POST['canvasData'])` and the call to savaData()

Comment: @RamRaider it looks like I was missing the `setRequestHeader`, but now the image string is destroyed or incomplete

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A quickly written demo that uses ajax to send the image data to a backend script for processing. You are right about the `setRequestHeader` being needed - it is better, once you have a working ajax function, to use it rather than rewriting each time IMO.

```
<?php
    if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST' ){
        ob_clean();
        print_r( $_POST );
        exit();
    }   
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en'>
    <head>
        <meta charset='utf-8' />
        <title>xhr - canvas - image data</title>
        <style>
            canvas{width:346px;height:288px;}
        </style>
        <script>

            const url=location.href;    //  ../controller/pictureController.php



            const takepicture=function( canvas ){
                let callback=function(r){
                    document.querySelector('pre').innerHTML=r
                }
                let xhr=new XMLHttpRequest();
                    xhr.onreadystatechange=function(){
                        if( this.readyState==4 && this.status==200 )callback( this.response );
                        console.info('state: %s status: %s',this.readyState,this.status)
                    };
                    xhr.open( 'POST', url, true );
                    xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type','application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
                    xhr.send( 'canvasData='+canvas.toDataURL('image/png') );
            }


            document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', e=>{
                let img=new Image();
                    img.onload=function(){

                        let canvas=document.querySelector('canvas');
                            canvas.width=img.width;
                            canvas.height=img.height;

                        let ctxt=canvas.getContext('2d');
                            ctxt.drawImage( img, 0, 0, img.width, img.height );

                        takepicture( canvas );                      
                    }
                img.src='/images/tmp/girl.jpg';
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <canvas></canvas>
        <pre></pre>
    </body>
</html>
```

[image: The image used in the demo]

The source image used in the demo/test

[image: The response]

The response from the ajax requestcan be seen under the image and is populated into the `pre` tag by the ajax callback